# D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM error causes

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I am playing music in backgroud. After I get "AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM" then my app crashes. It suddenly stop playin music.

I am getting this error from devices have android 11 or android 10.

```
val mediaSessionCompat = MediaSessionCompat(context, "NotificationActionService") //CreateNotification.kt:32
```

Log:

```
2021-01-12 14:49:56.655 12908-12908/com.dev.test5 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-01-12 14:49:56.658 12908-12908/com.dev.test5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: , PID: 12908
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.media.session.ISessionController android.media.session.ISession.getController()' on a null object reference
        at android.media.session.MediaSession.<init>(MediaSession.java:199)
        at android.media.session.MediaSession.<init>(MediaSession.java:156)
        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi21.createSession(MediaSessionCompatApi21.java:46)
        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:3380)
        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi28.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:3906)
        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:493)
        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:456)
        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:430)
        at com.dev.test5.aui.base.fragment.exercise.listening.notification.CreateNotification.createNotification(CreateNotification.kt:32)
        at com.dev.test5.aui.base.fragment.exercise.listening.ListeningExerciseActivity.setVariables(ListeningExerciseActivity.kt:464)
        at com.dev.test5.aui.base.fragment.exercise.listening.ListeningExerciseActivity.run(ListeningExerciseActivity.kt:495)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:939)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an internal Android MediaSessions limit `SESSION_CREATION_LIMIT_PER_UID = 100;`

You should release `MediaSession` instances that you don't need anymore.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70303019/8897392)